SQL assign a value from a column in table A until all the values of a column in table B are populated
I have a table box as depicted below.
box_name
---------
box1
box2
box3
box4
box5
box6
box7
box8
box9
box10

And another table color as shown below
color
------
red
blue
green

My objective is to assign a color to each box so that each of the box has a color associated with it. The assignment of color to boxes can be random.
Depicted below is how the output may look like
box_name    color
------------------
box1        red
box2        blue
box3        green
box4        green
box5        red
box6        blue
box7        red
box8        red
box9        blue
box10       green

I am trying to use a recursive query to achieve this, but it is not working. Below is the query which I have tried
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS 
(
SELECT B.box_name, C.color_box, C.rnc
FROM
((SELECT
BOX_NAME,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BOX_NAME ASC) AS rnb
FROM box) B
JOIN
(SELECT
COLOR_BOX,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLOR_BOX ASC) AS rnc
FROM color) C
ON B.rnb = C.rnc)
  
UNION

SELECT B.box_name, CTE.color_box,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BOX_NAME ASC) AS rnb1
FROM box B 
JOIN CTE ON B.rnb1 = CTE.rnc 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE

My question is does recursive query work for a physical table, or can we combine temporary result subsets in a recursive query. If yes, then how can I modify my query to work.

You can use a cross join and pick a random row per box:
SELECT DISTINCT ON (box.box_name)
       box.box_name,
       color.color
FROM box
   CROSS JOIN color
ORDER BY box.box_name, random();

